# 1951 Soviet Mathematics Olympiad Number Theory

Tags: number-theory

> The positive integers $a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n$ are such that each is less than $1000$, and $\operatorname{lcm}\left(a_i, a_j\right) > 1000\,\forall i, j, i\neq j$. Show that $$\sum_{i = 1}^n\frac1{a_i} < 2.$$ ($1951$ Russian Mathematics Olympiad)

In the solution, it stated that for
$\frac{1000}{m+1} < a < \frac{1000}{m+1}$, then there are $m$ multiples of a that do not exceed 1000.

I quote:

"Let $k_1$ the number of $a_i$
in the interval $( \frac{1000}{2}
, 1000]$, $a_i$ in
(
1000
3
,
1000
2
], etc. Then there are $k_1 + 2k_2 + 3k_3 + · · ·$ integers, no greater
than $1000$, that are multiples of at least one of the $a_i$
. But the multiples are
distinct so"

$k_1+2k_2 ... < 1000$
$2k_1 + 3k_2 ... = (k_1 + k_2 ...) + (k_1+2k_2 + 3k_3) <1000 +n < 2000$

I am lost after the 2nd Sentence, what numbers $a_i$ do we get in the intervals? It also did not explain why the $lcm(a_i, a_j)$ would be more than 1000.

Maybe someone could explain it to me that is more clear?

Comment: If $\frac{1000}{m+1}<a\leq\frac{1000}{m}$ then there are $m$ multiples of $a$ not larger than $1000$. This is because $1\cdot a\leq\frac{1}{m}\cdot 1000<1000$, $2\cdot a\leq\frac{2}{m}\cdot 1000$, ..., $m\cdot a\leq\frac{m}{m}\cdot 1000=1000$. Then they define $k_m$ to be the number of $a_i$ in the interval $(1000/(m+1),1000/m]$. These $a_i$ are those that have $m$ multiples not larger than $1000$, by the first observation. Note that because $lcd(a_i,a_j)>1000$, none of those multiples of the $a_i$ that are less than or equal to $1000$ are common multiples of two $a_i$. Then there is no ...

Comment: ... double counting when you count all those multiples together. each of the $k_m$ $a_i$s has $m$ multiples not exceeding $1000$. Therefore, there are $k_1+2k_2+3k_3+...$ multiples of all the $a_i$s that do not exceed $1000$. So, $k_1+2k_2+3k_3+...\leq 1000$.

Comment: Now, from $lcm(a_i,a_j)>1000$ and $a_i\leq 1000$ we also get that all $a_i$ are different. Therefore $n\leq 1000$. Hence $2k_1+3k_3+...=(k_1+k_2+...)+(k_1+2k_2+3k_3+...)\leq n + 1000< 2000$. Now each $k_m$ one of the $a_i$ satisfies $\frac{1000}{m+1}<a_i$. Therefore, $\frac{1000}{a_i}<m+1$. When the sum $\sum\frac{1000}{a_i}<(m+1)k_m$, where the sum is only of the $i$-th counted by the $k_m$. Therefore $\sum_{i=1}^{m}\frac{1000}{a_i}<2k_1+3k_2+...<2000$ and the required inequality follows.

Comment: In your 3rd comment, you mean that each $a_i$ in $k_m$ satisfies $\frac{1000}{m+1} < a_i $ right?

Comment: Yes, it is written like the sentence: "Each $5$ of the dogs has a collar".

Comment: Although maybe it can also be said: "Each dog of the $5$ has a collar".